# x509 Certificate installation using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, x509certificate2

I have an issue when installing x509 certificate in the system through vb.net.

Installation itself is successful, but when I do install it through the code I do get one entry in Certificate Management window as displayed bellow:

[image]

However when I install it manually using import function in Certificate Management window I do get two entries in the list for this certificate:

[image]

The problem that I am facing is that when I use this certificate to perform certain tasks (passing some info to the third party service) it only works when it is manually imported (there are two entries in the certificate list). It looks like when installing certificate through the code, it doesn't install it fully. I done lots of research on code used to install certificate and it looks fairly straight forward:

```
    With ofd
            .Title = "Select Certificate"
            .FileName = ""
            .CheckFileExists = True
            If .ShowDialog <> Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
                Dim cert As New X509Certificate2(.FileName, "xxxxxxx", X509KeyStorageFlags.UserKeySet)
                Dim certStore As New X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser)
                certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite)
                certStore.Add(cert)
                certStore.Close()
            End If
        End With
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: What is the type/extension of the certificate file? is it .cer or .pfx maybe? Did you use the same file when you did the comparison between installing it manually vs via code?

Comment: By the way, the second certificate seems to be the issuer certificate. You would most probably want to install it in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities folder instead of the Personal folder (assuming of course that you trust the issuer of this certificate).

Comment: Extension of the certificate file is .p12. Yes, I am using the same file for both installations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [X509Certificate2Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2collection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class like this:

```
Dim collection = New X509Certificate2Collection()

collection.Import(.FileName, "xxxxxxx", X509KeyStorageFlags.UserKeySet)

Dim store = New X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser)

store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite)

Try
    For Each certificate As X509Certificate2 In collection
        store.Add(certificate)
    Next
Finally
    store.Close()
End Try
```

This allows you to import all the certificates from the file.

Please note that the right place for CA certificates is the Trusted Root Certification Authorities folder. And you only should import certificates there if you trust the issuer.